# How to convert GIF files to PNG or JPEG in OS X with command line?

Tags: macos, conversion, jpeg, png

I have 10k+ GIF files that I need to convert to PNG or JPEG preferably using command line so that I can automate it. I'm not worried about losing quality or transparency, just need to prepare files for OCR software.

When trying to use `convertformat`, I get this:

```
Error in pixReadStreamGif: function not present
Error in pixReadStream: gif: no pix returned
Error in pixRead: pix not read
Error in pixGetDepth: pix not defined
Error in pixWrite: pix not defined
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

No need for any additional tools. OS X has `sips`, which can convert images to (almost) any format.

For example, to convert every `.gif` to `.jpeg`, putting them into a folder called `jpegs`:

```
mkdir jpegs
sips -s format jpeg ./*.gif --out jpegs
```

Or, to recursively convert them using `find`, which will place a JPEG file with the same name as the GIF next to it.

```
find . -iname "*.gif" -type f -exec sh -c 'sips -s format jpeg "$0" --out "${0%.gif}.jpeg"' {} \;
```

Comment: [man sips](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/sips.1.html) ← This manual page is for Mac OS X version 10.9: sips -- scriptable image processing system.

Comment: See below for updated answer.

Answer (score 3):

Rather old question I see, but unfortunately the slhck's solution two doesn't work for me (OS X Mountain Lion, bash) I get an error.

This one works for me (after `cd my_dir_with_gif` command of course):

```
for i in *.gif; do sips -s format jpeg "${i}" --out "${i%gif}jpg"; done
```

And if you want to set the jpg compression as well (`[low|normal|high|best|<percent>]`)

```
for i in *.gif; do sips -s format jpeg -s formatOptions 100 "${i}" --out "${i%jpg}png"; done
```

For other formats you should change extensions (remembering the sips jpg format is always `jpeg`, the extension could be `.jpg`)

This using `sips` but even better ImageMagick. It's a great tool, and I suggest to install it using `brew` see [brew homepage](http://brew.sh)

Answer (score 0):

Check out [GraphicsMagick](http://www.graphicsmagick.org/) or [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/), they have command line tools for all sort of mangling of graphics files (including boring stuff like transforming to another format).